# Best way to handle JS events for components nested in components?

Tags: javascript, jquery, components, jquery-events, event-bubbling

For example, a tabs component within a tabs component. I'm currently working on the next major version of Titon Toolkit (https://github.com/titon/toolkit), 2.0, and I want to support this scenario as easily as possible. Currently in 1.0, nesting is not possible.

The components in Toolkit use event delegation for binding interactions within a component. The events are bound to the component wrapper (top level parent) and delegated to all children within it using classes (in 2.0 they use data attributes for CSS/JS de-coupling). Now you can see the problem. If events are bound to the parent component, they will also be bound to any nested components as well as they share the same class name (or data attribute). Furthermore, any events bound to the child will now have 2 events being triggered, oh no!

A brief example of the problem.

```
<div class="tabs" id="tabs-1" data-tab>
    <ul class="tab-nav" data-tab-nav>
        <li><a href="">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <section class="tab-section" data-tab-section></section>
    <section class="tab-section" data-tab-section></section>
    <section class="tab-section" data-tab-section>

        <div class="tabs" id="tabs-2" data-tab>
            <ul class="tab-nav" data-tab-nav>
                <li><a href="">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">3</a></li>
            </ul>

            <section class="tab-section" data-tab-section></section>
            <section class="tab-section" data-tab-section></section>
            <section class="tab-section" data-tab-section></section>
        </div>

    </section>
</div>
```

With events being bound as such:

```
$('#tabs-1').on('click', '[data-tab-nav] a', showSection); // Also being bound to #tabs-2 elements
$('#tabs-2').on('click', '[data-tab-nav] a', showSection);
```

And here's the dilemma I am in. What is the easiest, or better yet, the least error prone approach to solving this? These are the only solutions I currently have.

1. Bind `stopPropagation()` on nested elements. Not a great solution as bubbling might be needed and will also need to be handled by the developer.
2. Use data attributes with values. For example, initializing the tabs component with a data attribute of `[data-tab="foo"]` will only bind events to elements with the same data attribute value, for example `[data-tab-nav="foo"] a`. So if the parent is `foo` and the child is `bar`, everything will be bound correctly. Will require more markup but has no down sides.
3. Use custom classes in the parent and child that be bound to and can be customized.

Thoughts? Suggestions?

Comment: Also note, the same problems apply to traversal through `find()`. As of right now, the 2nd option fixes both event binding and traversing.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way I can think of doing it (demo: http://jsfiddle.net/brdgc05d/3/):

```
var tabClasses = ['#tabs-1', '#tabs-2'];

$.each(tabClasses, function(index, tabClass) {
   $(tabClass).on('click', '[data-tab-nav] a', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       if ( $(e.delegateTarget).parents('[data-tab]').length ) { // must use delegateTarget, otherwise $(e.delegateTarget) would be the <a> element they clicked rather than $('#tabs-n')
           // is a child, so you could abort the event here
           alert(tabClass + ' clicked and IS a child');
       } else {
           // is not a child
           alert(tabClass + ' clicked and is NOT a child');
       }
    });
});
```